# Java reading upper/lower case characters and converting them

Tags: java, case

Okay, so I have another program. This one should be rather self explanatory. This program is made to read characters from continuous java input (line after line) until the . is entered. It then converts all Upper case characters to Lower case and vice versa (Special characters or numbers are NOT modified). It then outputs the changes.

```
import java.io.*;
class textchanger
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader (inStream);
    String inputValues;
    char charCounter = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome the to text modifier!");
    System.out.println("Inset any character(s) you wish: ");

    inputValues = userInput.readLine();

    while ((inputValues = userInput.readLine()) != null && inputValues.indexOf('.') == -1) {
    }
    int length = inputValues.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        charCounter = inputValues.charAt(i);
    }
    if(Character.isUpperCase(charCounter)) {
    Character.toLowerCase(charCounter);
    System.out.println(charCounter);
    }
    else if(Character.isLowerCase(charCounter)) {
    Character.toUpperCase(charCounter);
    System.out.println(charCounter);
    }

    }
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. The current error(s) that I receive is nothing being displayed after the "." character is input.

Comment: You declared `CharCounter` twice, on lines 9 and 22, in nested scopes. Remove the `char` from line 22.

Comment: The current error is now that CharCouner may not have been initialized.

Answer (score 3):

`CharCounter` is already defined in the scope of the `main` method. Replace

```
char CharCounter = inputValues.charAt(i);
```

with

```
CharCounter = inputValues.charAt(i);
```

After doing this the variable will need to be initialized as all local variables are required to be initialized in Java:

```
char CharCounter = 0;
```

And use Java naming conventions when naming variables such as `charCounter`.

---

```
class TextChanger {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(inStream);
        String inputValues;

        System.out.println("Welcome the to text modifier!");
        System.out.println("Inset any character(s) you wish: ");

        while ((inputValues = userInput.readLine()) != null
                && inputValues.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            int length = inputValues.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                char charCounter = inputValues.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isUpperCase(charCounter)) {
                    System.out.println(Character.toLowerCase(charCounter));
                } else if (Character.isLowerCase(charCounter)) {
                    System.out.println(Character.toUpperCase(charCounter));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The java compiler now says that it may not have been initialized. :/

Comment: You can either initialize as above or have a single declaration of `charCounter` within the `for` loop as @StinePike has done

Comment: I have that edit in, however now it will compile fine, but nothing comes out of the input.

Comment: +1 for referencing my answer :D .. anyways my suggestion is to declare the variable within for scope. because it is best practice to declare variable within shortest possible scope

Comment: Declaring the variable in the scope isn't the problem right now. It's just that when it compiles and it asks for the input, after the "." is entered in, the program simply just... Ends.

Comment: That is expected as a dot `.` is neither uppercase or lowercase so your output is empty. You need to put _everything_ into the `while` loop if you want to display converted output

Comment: How would I do that, per say? The program is supposed to end when the "." character is input, and right then.

Comment: Just read in the input once in the loop itself as shown above

Comment: I tried editing it as such, I think I may need to scrap it and get some help in completely revamping the program. For some reason, it still not output anything.

Comment: That's because you still have your character conversion outside the `while` loop. if you place it inside the loop as per my last update above it will work. Don't forget to remove the `readLine` statement just before entering the loop...

Comment: How is it "outside"? I see it inside the loop the way you have it. I also tried taking out the readLine statement that was outside, and it still did nothing.

Comment: I'm going by the last update to the question and there is a closing brace immediately after the `while` statement. Anyway I've updated the complete program now which definitely works

Answer (score 1):

you were converting the character after for loop while you are declaring the CharCounter in for loop. Use like following

```
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char CharCounter = inputValues.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isUpperCase(CharCounter)) {
            Character.toLowerCase(CharCounter);
            System.out.println(CharCounter);
        }else if(Character.isLowerCase(CharCounter)) {
            Character.toUpperCase(CharCounter);
            System.out.println(CharCounter);
        }    
    }
```